# While migrate date in to CRM it stores date with 4 hours ahead

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

While Migrate data in to CRM it saves date and time with 4 hours ahead. Is it possible to save date as same as source.

Comment: Timezone difference.

Comment: @ArunVinoth you have any idea to run ssis packages containing kingswaysoft  in SSMS itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51595348/7920473

Answer (score 0):

If you pull the date in UTC format from your source you can select "Send datetime values in UTC format" within our CRM Destination component.